# Can you fix drooping eyelids with exercises?

Tags: medical-science, ophthalmology

I stumbled upon this YouTube video which gives exercises to fix drooping eyelids:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYBd6t1k-38

The medical term used to qualify drooping eyelids is [ptosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptosis_(eyelid)) (or blepharoptosis).

The website [All About Vision](https://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/ptosis-natural-home-remedies/) states the following:

> Unfortunately, droopy eyelids caused by ptosis cannot be cured with natural treatments, exercises or other home remedies. The nature of ptosis is what prevents it from being treated naturally.

Even though I do not really understand what they mean by "droopy eyelids caused by ptosis" (from what I've seen when doing my research, "ptosis" only seems to be another word to designate droopy eyelids, but I may be wrong), they assert that there is no way to fix droopy eyelids without resorting to surgery.

[Medical News Today](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/droopy-eyelids-exercises#do-they-work) indicates that "[n]o research on exercises for droopy eyelids exists", but still provides a list of exercises one could do to possibly fix droopy eyelids. They link a [2018 study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5885810/) by Alam et al. (*Association of Facial Exercise With the Appearance of Aging*), the conclusion of which is the following:

> A 30-minute daily or alternate-day facial exercise program sustained over 20 weeks may modestly improve the facial appearance of selected middle-aged women. […] Participants were highly satisfied, noting significant improvement in 18 of 20 facial features.

Another website named [HexaHealth](https://www.hexahealth.com/blog/droopy-eyelid-exercises-fix-ptosis-instantly-without-surgery) also gives a list of exercises which may help with the issue.

Are the exercises presented on these websites really useful for fixing drooping eyelids and is it possible to fix this issue without surgery?